# Query to compare 2 table results and filter out certain records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to perform a query whereby I can extract certain document entry numbers for deletion. (SQL Server 2008)
The first query gives me the results from a table OINV.

```
SELECT DocEntry AS "DocEntryINV" , Comments, DocTotal
FROM OINV WHERE DocDate BETWEEN '10-27-2012' AND '10-29-2012' AND Comments IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY DocTotal ASC, Comments
```

The second from a table ORIN

```
SELECT DocEntry AS "DocEntryCN" , Comments, JrnlMemo, DocTotal
FROM ORIN WHERE DocDate BETWEEN '10-27-2012' AND '10-29-2012' AND Comments IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY DocTotal ASC, Comments
```

**OINV sample results**

```
DocEntryINV   JrnlMemo   DocTotal
1             kaka-19        500
3             kaka-19        500
5             kaka-19        500
6             kaka-19        500
7             Rob-23         750
9             Rob-23         750
10            Alex-09        1000
11            Olma-08        1150
12            Paul-17        1250 
13            Paul-17        1250
16            Paul-17        1250
17            Rita-99        1300
19            Rita-99        1300
```

**ORIN sample results**

```
DocEntryCN    Comments    JrnlMemo      DocTotal
67            reverse     kaka-19       500
69            reverse     kaka-19       500
70            reverse     kaka-19       500
71            reverse     kaka-19       500
74            reverse     kaka-19       500
75            reverse     Rob-23        750
77            reverse     Rob-23        750
78            reverse     Rob-23        750
79            reverse     Rob-23        750
84            reverse     Paul-17       1250
86            reverse     Paul-17       1250
87            reverse     Paul-17       1250
```

For the table OINV, the duplicates arose from a point of sale software that pushed duplicates of invoices to an ERP database table, OINV. A program meant to correct the situation by creating credit notes to nullify Invoices didn't work well, sometimes creating more credit notes than were invoices in the first place. (Invoices number 45,000+ in total). Sometimes credit notes were not created where needed for invoice duplicates.

How can I create a query using both tables where I can be able to reverse the extra entries on the ORIN table, if they exist? I need the query to return the results of the
DocEntryCN numbers to be reversed such as the following results for the above scenario.

```
DocEntryCN    Comments    JrnlMemo      DocTotal
67            reverse     kaka-19       500
69            reverse     kaka-19       500
75            reverse     Rob-23        750
77            reverse     Rob-23        750
78            reverse     Rob-23        750
84            reverse     Paul-17       1250
90            reverse     Rita-99       1300
```

NB. Comments stores Invoice numbers that are unique. If any two comments in the OINV table are the same, it means there is a duplicate error. The JrnlMemo field in the ORIN table stores the OINV invoice numbers. For any invoice repetitions no. k, the correct number of credit notes to reverse should be k - 1.

Comment: seems that you are missing 3 * Rita-99s in the ORIN sample

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I did that just in case the original program correction did not produce any credit notes to correct the original duplication for Rita-99

Comment: are you sure the column names are correct in OINV sample result ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk The first columns relate to the DocEntry columns for both tables in SAP B1. Changed column 2 OINV to JrnlMemo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that Rita's data does not exist in the ORIN sample, so it can't be in the result. I hope this can solve your problem:

```
;with a as
(
select row_number() over(partition by JrnlMemo order by DocEntry) rn,
count(*) over (partition by JrnlMemo) cnt
, DocEntry DocEntryCN, Comments, JrnlMemo, DocTotal from @ORIN
FROM ORIN WHERE DocDate BETWEEN '2012-10-27' AND '2012-10-29' AND Comments IS NOT NULL 
), b as
(
select JrnlMemo, count(*)-2 count 
from oinv
WHERE DocDate BETWEEN '2012-10-27' AND '2012-10-29' AND Comments IS NOT NULL 
group by JrnlMemo
)
select a.DocEntryCn, a.Comments, a.JrnlMemo, a.DocTotal
from a join b on a.cnt > a.rn + b.count and a.JrnlMemo = b.JrnlMemo
order by DocEntryCn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Let me check this out.

Comment: Worked great for the thousands of entries. I will modify for the case when less or no credit notes were created for duplicate invoices.